# PDF from byte array from sql server in mvc

Tags: jquery, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

**Three steps I am following.**

- Create PDF in one view.
- Store in database in byte[] form which column is `varbinary(max)`
- Retrieve from database and show as PDF when user click.

**Creating PDF:**

```
    public byte[] PDF(List<DeliveryOrderDetail> deliveryOrdList)
            {
                byte[] result;
                string headingText = "Guide";
                try 
                {

                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        Document doc = new Document();
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms).CloseStream = false;
                        PdfPTable pdfTab = new PdfPTable(3);
                        Paragraph heading = new Paragraph(headingText, new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 18f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK));
                        Paragraph ItemDetail = new Paragraph("Items in Delivery Order Box:", new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 12f, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK));
                        heading.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        ItemDetail.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(heading);
                        pdfTab.HorizontalAlignment = 1; // 0- Left, 1- Center, 2- right
                        pdfTab.SpacingBefore = 20f;
                        pdfTab.SpacingAfter = 20f;
                        // pdfTab.AddCell("Sl. No.");
                        pdfTab.AddCell("ItemName");
                        pdfTab.AddCell("BoxId");
                        pdfTab.AddCell("Manufacturer");
                        doc.Add(ItemDetail);
                        foreach (var item in deliveryOrdList)
                        {

                            pdfTab.AddCell(item.Name);
                            pdfTab.AddCell(item.Id.ToString());
                            pdfTab.AddCell(item.Manufacturer);

                        }

                        doc.Add(pdfTab);
                        doc.Close();
                        result = ms.GetBuffer();
                    }


                    return result;

                }
                catch(Exception e )
                {

                }
                return null;
            }
```

**Storing result which is byte[] into database table with `db.savechanges();`**

**On image click :**

```
     var pdf  will get the database field which contains binary data 

        jQuery: when image is clicked go to controller

           <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.Pdf').click(function () {

                        var pdf = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) input').val();;

                        alert(pdf);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/ship/PDF",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data:JSON.stringify({ pdf: pdf }),
                            //data:{pdf:pdf},
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

                        })
                    })
                })
            </script>
```

**In Controller: Following method is written which accept as string :**

```
                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult PDF(string  pdf)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        byte[] byteInfo =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pdf);
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
                        workStream.Position = 0;


                        return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");

                    }
                    //to catch the exception 
                    catch (Exception _Exception)
                    {

                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

Here I am unable to see `pdf.in` browser when image is clicked. I have tried all options but unable to get it. If I write it in file. PDF will not get opened

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\personal\testpdf.pdf", byteInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are sending request to the controller will only send back the
 //file for download but won't open in the window. I am not sure if are able to Generated //PDF file or not . First thing should be that you are able to Generate the correct PDF //file . if you want to acheive this that when user clicks and file is download then you //should do this way.

```
 public ActionResult DownLoadFile()
        {
           string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/PDFFOLDER/YorFile.pdf");
             var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
           return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "yourfilename.pdf");

      //Another way can be using direct stream 

   //  var bytes = as you are getting these bytes from DB;   
    return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "yourfilename.pdf");

         }
```

And if you want to Open the file in new Tab, then you can do some thing like this on Server and Write your actual file in some folder.
//System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/PDFFOLDER/YorFile.pdf"), byteInfo);

```
                        function ViewPdfInNewWindow(filename)
                         {
                            var linkHref = "www.mysite.com";

                            var str = linkHref.toString();

                            linkHref = str + "/PDFFOLDER/" + filename;     


                            childWindow = window.open(linkHref); //Open in new window 


                        }




Let me know if it works !
```

Comment: return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "yourfilename.pdf"); i tried using this but it is not working

Comment: What is the error ? try to make sure that you have right bytes for PDF files. you can write those bytes on File to make sure you have correct PDF. Another hint is just take any PDF from internet , Read its bytes and try then try to use this method.

Comment: Can you write your PDF on file and open it in Acrobat reader?